# What does :^ stand for in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Not sure if I am searching in a wrong way, but couldn't find the answer anywhere online...

What does :^ stand for in Ruby? In particular trying to understand the code below:

```
# this returns the element in array_of_numbers, which occurs an odd number of times
array_of_numbers.reduce(:^)
# this returns 0
[1,2,3].reduce(:^)
# this returns 4
[1,2,3,4].reduce(:^)
```

Was tying to understand the logic playing with different arrays, but I think I am missing something. Thanks in advance!

Comment: the way you would search for this is first google for `special character names` to find out the char name is 'caret', then google `ruby caret symbol`. Really no need to post an SO question for something that broad and simple.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-5E

Comment: The docs for [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) contain an example to _"sum some numbers"_: `(5..10).reduce(:+) #=> 45`. That `:+` is your `:^` – a symbol indicating the binary method to apply.

Answer (score 3):

`:` in front of a name produces a [Symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Symbol.html).

In some contexts, a Symbol can be used as a message to an object. The object that receives the message reacts to it by calling its method that has the same name as the symbol (if such a method exists).
In your examples, this method is [`Integer#^`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Integer.html#method-i-5E), which represent the [exclusive OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) bit operator.

`[1,2,3].reduce(:^)` is, more or less, the same as `1 ^ 2 ^ 3`.<sup>*</sup>
Being an OOP language, `1 ^ 2 ^ 3` in Ruby is syntactic sugar for `(1.^(2)).^(3)`.

Read more about the [exclusive OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) bit operator.

---

<sup>*</sup> They produce the same result but the explicit expression should be faster.

Comment: “_In some contexts, a Symbol can be used as a message to an object._”— plain wrong. `&` when in front of passed to the method argument, simply **calls `to_proc` on whatever follows it**. `Symbol#to_proc` in turn simply delegates to the method on the receiver with the name equal to this symbol.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin you say _"plain wrong"_ and explain how `&` works, but there is no `&` here.

Comment: @Stefan I quoted the sentence I said “plain wrong” about, though.

Comment: @axiac Thank you, didn't know about the XOR concept before.

Comment: @axiac as well as String: `[1,2,3].reduce('+')`

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Why is it *plain* wrong? Is it(`:^`) not a message to a _memo_, which is same type as array elements? I.e. is it *plain* different from `(1.^(2)).^(3)` ?

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk there is no notion of _message_ in Ruby, so I doubt I follow. It evidently results in `(1.^(2)).^(3)`, but sending a message to the object has nothing to do with it. `Enumerable#reduce/1` handles both `Symbol` and `String` arguments to call the respective method.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin in OOP, a method call is also known as [*message passing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Dynamic_dispatch/message_passing). While most OOP languages enforce a strong link between a method name and the type of the object that is used to invoke it (in C++, one cannot call `a->foo()` if the class of `a` does not define method `foo()`), Ruby detaches the messages (the method names) from the target objects and allows sending the messages either as strings or symbols to the objects without even knowing if the target objects know how to handle them.

Comment: ... The target object reacts to a message either by running its method with the same name as the message, if such a method exists, or its `method_missing` method otherwise.

Comment: If that is called “a message to the object,” then it’s possible in literally **all contexts** in Ruby.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin _"there is no notion of message in Ruby"_. Matz doesn't agree with you: 8.4.3, `Object#send` desciption - https://books.google.nl/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA274&lpg=PA274&dq=ruby+Object+send+message+Matzumoto&source=bl&ots=fKFmzi2uhA&sig=ACfU3U1VTUvVX1Sovc7W6Gwt5jx8f8aDhg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXl_XMvP_hAhXyyIUKHf6jDYIQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=ruby%20Object%20send%20message%20Matzumoto&f=false

Comment: _"In Ruby, a Symbol can be used as a message to an object"_ – accepting a symbol representing a method is specific to the `reduce` method. Other methods don't work like that, e.g. `[1, 2, 3].map(:to_s)` would raise an error. Saying that you can do this "in Ruby" sounds like a general concept or a built-in feature of the language. This is not the case.

Comment: @Stefan also, that is not the case here as well. If one clicks on [`Enumerable#reduce` → show source](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce), they might easily see that no message is passed anywhere, but the same `to_proc` conversion is being done explicitly as if an ampersand took it’s place. That `reduce`/`inject` all of a sudden accepting symbol argument for no reason is the  weirdest thing in great Ruby enumerables design.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: I know that both you and Stefan have great expertise with Ruby, knowing how the things work behind the surface. But today it seems you both prefer to be nitpickers. This is an entry-level answer to an entry-level question. I am not more advanced on Ruby than the OP and I provided an answer on my knowledge level that can be understood by other Ruby beginners. Please feel free to write your own answers if you don't like mine. But be aware that digging into the technical details of procs and the Ruby source code is not the right path for the level of this question.